# Returning procedure execution code in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have a stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetNotExecutedOrders`(IN contractID INT(11))
BEGIN
 SELECT idContract, idOrder, ProductID, Quantity, (SUM(`order`.Quantity))*(product.Price) as 'Total amount'
 FROM typography.contract
 JOIN typography.`order` ON contract.idContract=`order`.ContractID
 JOIN typography.product ON `order`.ProductID=product.idProduct
 WHERE idContract=contractID and ExecutionDate IS NULL
 GROUP BY idOrder
 ORDER BY idOrder;
END
```

I need to fix it so it returns an execution code <> 0 if there is no contract with such contract ID, and a list of contracts and an execution code = 0 if there is a contract with that contract ID.

Comment: Use an `IF` statement.

Comment: Yes, i tried that, but I don't know how to return the code itself. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I suggest adding an `OUT` parameter for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `OUT` parameter for the code. Then use a `COUNT(*)` query to set it.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetNotExecutedOrders`(IN contractID INT(11), OUT executionCode INT)
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 INTO executionCode
    FROM typography.contract
    JOIN typography.`order` ON contract.idContract=`order`.ContractID
    JOIN typography.product ON `order`.ProductID=product.idProduct
    WHERE idContract=contractID and ExecutionDate IS NULL;

    IF (executionCode)
        SELECT idContract, idOrder, ProductID, Quantity, (SUM(`order`.Quantity))*(product.Price) as 'Total amount'
        FROM typography.contract
        JOIN typography.`order` ON contract.idContract=`order`.ContractID
        JOIN typography.product ON `order`.ProductID=product.idProduct
        WHERE idContract=contractID and ExecutionDate IS NULL
        GROUP BY idOrder
        ORDER BY idOrder;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you please explain how does COUNT(*) > 0 work? I don't understand why it can be used without an IF statement

Comment: Comparison functions and operators evaluate to `true` or `false`, which are represented as `1` and `0` in MySQL.